# OverridesDefaultStyle together with BasedOn in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

If you set `OverridesDefaultStyle` to true, the default style won't be used.
What is the result of using `BasedOn` at the same time?

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type c:MenuButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Do the two instructions contradict each other in any way?
Is it the default style underlying `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` that will be ignored?
In this particular example I don't see any difference whether `OverridesDefaultStyle` is true or false.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use both of those properties, you would end up with a `MenuButton` object (in your example) that takes *all* of its `Style` information from your `MenuButton` `Style` and the remainder of the properties would come from your `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` `Style`. At least, that is true in theory, as I've never actually had to use that arrangement.

In particular, setting the `OverridesDefaultStyle` property to `True` is 'supposed' to make the styled element *not use theme style properties*, instead getting all of its `Style` values from *local application styles*. However, I have also found that in some instances, setting this property to `True` does not seem to make any difference.

On the other hand, when this property setting *does* work, it will remove the default `ControlTemplate` and so to *support the same features as the default theme styles, you must supply an alternate style with a control template that replicates the same structure*.

> Italic text comes from the [`FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.overridesdefaultstyle.aspx) page on MSDN