# Change the background color of a single DataGrid column header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm using a WPF `DataGrid` and I want to change a single column header background color, without affecting the others.

I found the following question:

[How to change column header's background color when using WPF datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486977/how-to-change-column-headers-background-color-when-using-wpf-datagrid/),

but this will change all column headers, and I only want to change one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use something like that:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

you're changing the `DataGridColumnHeader` `Style` for ALL the `ColumnHeader`s in that scope, because the `Style` has not been given a `Key`.

Now, pretend that the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` is a `List<C>`, where `C` is a class with `string` properties called `A` and `B`. This is what you can do to set only the `Style` of column `A`:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           Key="SpecialHeaderStyle"> <!-- here I set the Style's Key -->
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- for this column I set the HeaderStyle property -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}"
                        Header="A"
                        HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SpecialHeaderStyle}"/>
    <!-- for this column I don't -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding B}"
                        Header="B"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You'll the special `Style` set only on Column `A`.

Just as an aside, give attention to this: if you change the `Style` in this way, you're setting a fixed background color that is not changing if you pass over with the Mouse. In order to make a more responsive header UI, you have to override its whole Template. Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/01/20/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid/) for a wider discussion.

Comment: I am using materialdesigninxaml that applies styles to my DataGrid to make it look nice.  When I use a HeaderStyle it seems to overwrite all the styles from materialdesigninxaml.  Is there a way to keep the styles from materialdesignxaml and only apply changes in the resource style?

Comment: @DavidLee try to go into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383347/overridesdefaultstyle-together-with-basedon-in-wpf). It might help you (but I'm not sure).